# ctrl+c does not stop printing big text file in ssh.net

Tags: c#, ssh

I am using Renci SSH.NET.
I am running **"slowcat.sh big_log.txt"** command. **big_log.txt** is a large file(around 500 MB). But if I try to stop printing log with ctrl+c it doesn't work.
Project Reference: https://github.com/npcook/terminal

```
               //connectionCode
                var authentications = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.KeyFilePath))
                {
                    var privateKeyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(settings.KeyFilePath, settings.KeyFilePassphrase);
                    authentications.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(settings.Username, privateKeyFile));
                }
                authentications.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(settings.Username, settings.Password));
                ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(settings.ServerAddress, settings.ServerPort, settings.Username, authentications.ToArray());

                Client = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
                Client.Connect();
                App.Client = Client;

                Client.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

                Stream = Client.CreateShellStream("xterm-256color", (uint) terminalCols, (uint) terminalRows, 0, 0, 1000);


 //sending byte by this function
public bool SendBytes(byte[] data, int index, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            //for ctrl+c data[0]=3,index=0,count=1
            writer.Write(data, index, count);
            return true;
        }
    }
//sending char
public bool SendChar(char data)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Flush();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
//running a loop which always checks for data in another function
while (stream.DataAvailable)//it's remain true after pressing ctrl+c
                {
                    if (DataAvailable != null)
                    {
                        DataAvailable(this, new DataAvailableEventArgs(0));
                    }

                }
```

I want to stop the execution immidiately after ctrl+c is pressed.|

Comment: How are you opening the shellstream to begin with? Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code to creating this ssh connection and running commands.

Comment: necessary codes added.thanks